# Searchbar with filter and from JSON data with Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm very new to Typescript and Ionic 2 and I'm trying to filter trough a json response with Ionic 2 search bar.

This is my code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  posts: any;
  private searchQuery: string = '';
  private items: string[];
  constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.initializeItems();

    this.http.get('https://domain.co/open.jsonp').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data;
        console.log(this.posts);

    });

  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = this.posts;
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }

}
```

And the Markup:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" [debounce]="500" placeholder="Suchen..."></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <h1>{{post.storeName}}</h1>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I this error when I search:

> item.toLowerCase is not a function

The JSON data looks like this:

```
[
{
storeName: "Avec Hauptbahnhof",
addressLink: "",
phone: "0326223902",
image: "",
description: "",
link: "",
openingHours: [
"05.30 - 22:00",
"05.30 - 22:00",
"05.30 - 22:00",
"05.30 - 22:00",
"05.30 - 22:00",
"06.30 - 22:00",
"7.00 - 22.00"
]
},
{
storeName: "Manor",
addressLink: "",
phone: "0326258699",
image: "",
customer: "",
description: "",
link: "",
openingHours: [
"09.00 - 18.30",
"09.00 - 18.30",
"09.00 - 18.30",
"09.00 - 21:00",
"09.00 - 18.30",
"08.00 - 17.00",
"Geschlossen"
]
}
]
```

Comment: Does `https://domain.co/open.jsonp` return a list of strings?

Comment: it returns a json object

Comment: Could you please add in the OP how that json object looks like?

Comment: sure, I've edited the question @sebaferreras

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hope the answer could help you :)

Comment: @sebaferreras I have a similar issue with ion-searchbar. I would be really grateful if you could help me out with it. 
Here's the link to my query- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095620/using-searchbar-to-filter-ion-cards-in-ionic-angular

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're getting that error because each *item* is not a string, but an object, so instead of doing

```
item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

You should do

```
item.storeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

Also please notice that in your view you're using the *posts* array

```
*ngFor="let post of posts"
```

But you should use the *items* array instead, because that's the one that is going to be filtered

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <h1>{{item.storeName}}</h1>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

---

Besides that, I'd do things a little bit different, just to make sure that the user is able to use the page **only** when the data is available (since you're using an http request to obtain it). In order to do so, I'd add a loading alert and would remove it as soon as the http request is done. As of Ionic2-beta.11, you could do that like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private posts: any; // <- I've added the private keyword 
  private searchQuery: string = '';
  private items: any; // <- items property is now of the same type as posts
  constructor(private http: Http, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

    // this.initializeItems(); <- you don't need this anymore

    // Show the loading message
    let loadingPopup = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Loading posts...'
    });

    this.http.get('https://domain.co/open.jsonp').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.posts = data;
        this.initializeItems();

        // Hide the loading message
        loadingPopup.dismiss();
    });
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = this.posts;
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.storeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) How and where did you learned ionic2 and typescipt? I'm moving now from ionic 1 to ionic 2.

Comment: I'd say that the best place to learn Ionic2 is [Ionic2 docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/). You're going to save a lot of time if you read about the components you're going to use in your project before _getting your hands dirty_ :)

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I have faced when I worked in angular 2 with ionic.

In our project, we have one method to get all product list and displayed the items by using *ngFor.

Whenever we make search by using ionic search bar, the input search text will be got by using "event.target.value". We have to check if the search text is matched in the items.

Code is,

```
   getAllProdcuts(isFrom, searchText){
      this.toDoService.getAllProdcuts().then((res) => {
        this.items = res;
            if(isFrom == 'search') {
                this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
                    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1);
                })
            }
        }, (err) => {

        });
    }

  getItems(ev: any) {

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        this.getAllProdcuts("search", val);
    }
  }
```

Here, we can get filtered items from the method.

Thanks.!